# Get the Window for a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, parent, jmenuitem

Is there a way to get the Window which a `JMenuItem` belongs to? I tried this proof of-concept:

```
JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
testFrame.setSize(300, 100);
testFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JMenuBar testBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu testMenu = new JMenu("Test");
JMenuItem testItem = new JMenuItem("Parent Test");

testItem.addActionListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("Has Top Level Ancestor: " + (testItem.getTopLevelAncestor() != null));
    System.out.println("Has Window Ancestor: " + (SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(testItem) != null));
});

testBar.add(testMenu);
testMenu.add(testItem);

testFrame.setJMenuBar(testBar);
testFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The output was:

```
Has Top Level Ancestor: false
Has Window Ancestor: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to print the parent of the menu item:

```
testItem.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(testItem.getParent().getClass().getSimpleName()));
```

It prints "JPopupMenu" rather than "JMenu", which means that `testMenu` is not the parent of `testMenuItem`. However, if you cast the parent class and call [`JPopupMenu#getInvoker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#getInvoker--), it will return the JMenu.

With this in mind, I created the following method:

```
private static Window getWindowAncestor(JMenuItem item) {
    Container parent = item.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof JPopupMenu)
        return SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(((JPopupMenu) parent).getInvoker());
    else if (parent instanceof Window)
        return (Window) parent;
    else
        return SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parent);
}
```

It works :)

Comment: Since `((JPopupMenu) parent).getInvoker()` will return a `Component` based result, couldn't you just use `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(parent);` and forego the loop?

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are correct. I think that approach is just a little nicer to look at as well. I updated my answer.